# Drupal, Ubercart: automatically complete orders (skipping pending status)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

can I automatically approve an order in Ubercart (skipping the "Pending" status).

I'm not performing payments on my website. I just want an user to submit orders, and store them as "Completed orders".

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Conditional Actions as applied to orders.